# CLI alternative to speedtest-cli?

Tags: networking, command-line

I am trying to remotely test the internet connection on a headless server and am looking for a cli to do so. Speedtest-cli seems to give wildly inaccurate results and inconsistencies compared to the website.

Are there any other good alternatives or methods I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give a try to [iperf](http://software.es.net/iperf/).

Run it on the server with `iperf3 -s` and on the client with `iperf3 -c server`

By default, the server listens on TCP port 5201.

For more details, look at the man page [iperf3(1)](http://software.es.net/iperf/invoking.html)